# R: apply functions that contain Excel-like relative references to other columns

Tags: r, dplyr

`dplyr` has `lag` and `lead` functions to access preceding and subsequent **rows** within tables. I'm looking for a similar functionality across **columns**.

For example, here is a table:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame('score1' = 1:5, 'score2' = 10:6, dif21 = NA_integer_, 
                 'score3' = 11:15, 'score4' = 20:16, dif43 = NA_integer_)
```

```
#      score1 score2 dif21 score3 score4 dif43
# 1      1     10    NA     11     20    NA
# 2      2      9    NA     12     19    NA
# 3      3      8    NA     13     18    NA
# 4      4      7    NA     14     17    NA
# 5      5      6    NA     15     16    NA
```

The table has a pattern of columns that repeats twice: two columns of scores, followed by an empty "dif" column that will hold calculated values.

I can operate on the "dif" columns using `mutate_at`:

```
df_calc <- df %>% 
  mutate_at(
  vars(dif21), 
  ~ score2 - score1
  ) %>% 
  mutate_at(
    vars(dif43), 
    ~ score4 - score3
  )
```

```
#     score1 score2 dif21 score3 score4 dif43
# 1      1     10     9     11     20     9
# 2      2      9     7     12     19     7
# 3      3      8     5     13     18     5
# 4      4      7     3     14     17     3
# 5      5      6     1     15     16     1
```

This gets me the calculated scores that I want in the "dif" columns. In general, the formula is to subtract the column two positions to the left of "dif" from the column one position to the left of "dif". This sort of relative column referencing is easily handled in Excel, but I don't know how to do it in R.

The actual application is a table with scores of columns, so a method for using a single formula with relative column references would be a huge efficiency.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a `baseR` option

```
idx <- which(startsWith(names(df), "dif"))
df[idx] <- df[idx - 1] - df[idx - 2]
```

Result

```
df
#  score1 score2 dif21 score3 score4 dif43
#1      1     10     9     11     20     9
#2      2      9     7     12     19     7
#3      3      8     5     13     18     5
#4      4      7     3     14     17     3
#5      5      6     1     15     16     1
```

---

The idea is first to get the positions of the column that start with "dif".

Then we simply subtract the column two positions to the left of each "dif" column from the column one position to the left of each "dif" column.

Answer (score 1):

Also in base R, we can do

```
df[c(F,F,T)] = df[c(F,T,F)] - df[c(T,F,F)]
```

which is a bit more concise that @markus's answer, but also probably less versatile and less clear. But fine for this simple example.

Comment: Thanks to both for your help. I ended up using @markus solution because I understood it intuitively at first glance. I favored that over dww's more concise solution.